# Embedded torus on $S^3$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology

Let $T= \left\{ (x,y,z,w) \in S^3: x^2+y^2 = 1/2 \quad \text{and} \quad  z^2 + w^2 =1/2\right\}$

I would like to construct a explicit embedding of $T$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ using the stereographic projection.

Let $f: S^3-\left\{(0,0,0,1)\right\} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by
$$
f(x,y,z,w) = \left(\frac{2x}{1-w},\frac{2y}{1-w},\frac{2z}{1-w}\right)=(x',y',z').
$$
I try to solve this equation
$2x= x'(1-w), 2y=y'(1-w),2z=z'(1-w)$, using the condition of set $T$. But I cannot find the embedding. Can anybody help me in my task? A hint for solve this problem will be a great help.

Comment: $$(\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}-\sqrt8)^2+z'^2=4.$$ Looks like a torus. The radius of the tube is $2$, the center runs along a circle at distance $\sqrt8$ from the $z'$-axis.